# Prevent image from dropping into a specific box using html5 drag and drop functionality

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I want to implement a project of website having two dropdown boxes A and B, and two images image1 and image2 such that only the user can drag image1 to only boxA and image2 to boxB but not image1 to boxB and image2 to boxA.How to prevent images from dropping into a specific box.
Plz help

Comment: @mishik am able to drag and drop images to a specified box but unable to prevent draggng an image to a unspecified box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to do this "drag'n'drop" feature (despite your question being with a HTML5 tag), with something like this:

`$("your_element").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });`

Take a look at the documentation [link](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert).